# JValue does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms, json.net

Just starting to use JSON.NET. I've created an empty WinForms app, included JSON.NET in Project|Add Reference. Then, just to get going, I copied a piece of code for a site:

```
var jsonString = @"{""Name"":""Rick"",""Company"":""West Wind"",""Entered"":""2012-03-16T00:03:33.245-10:00""}";

dynamic json = JValue.Parse(jsonString);

// values require casting
string name = json.Name;
string company = json.Company;
DateTime entered = json.Entered;
```

I get the error:

> JValue does not exist in the current context

The version that comes with VS-2013 is 4.5

The `NewtonSoft.json.dll` file is where the reference points to. I assume that `JValue` is in JSON.NET 4.5, so I haven't tried downloading the most recent version.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have `using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq`?

Comment: woa, *I've created an empty WinForms app* and you have tagged your question with *asp.net* ...??

Comment: OK, fair enough! a Windows Forms Application

Answer (score 3):

Use it in this way:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject json  = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString);
```

Comment: Thanks. I've added 'using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq',  and it works fine.